# Jquery ajax POST request to a python file

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I'm trying to implement a POST request to a python file using jquery but I keep getting an internal server error. Im new to all of this so any help'd be great!

function sentimentUpload() {

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://sandbox.ceit.uq.edu.au/wordtools/cgi-bin/sentiment_engine.py",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify( {"data": {"info" : processed_info}} ),
    success: function(data) {
        processed_info = jQuery.parseJSON(data).info;

        console.log(data);
        //fillTags();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the server error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test your server side code with mock POST data first using these chrome plugins:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Also validate the returned JSON data using a online JSON validator:
http://json.parser.online.fr